# Express multer upload doesnt work

Tags: node.js, express, multer, body-parser

I have a problem with my uploader. I think everything with code is right and still the file isnt created in uploads folder. Also when i try to console.log(req.files) i get an empty array. I try to make it locally
Here is the code:

```
const   express = require("express"),
        app = express(),
        multer = require("multer"),
        bodyParser=require("body-parser"),


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + mime.extension(file.mimetype));
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage : storage }).array('userPic');

app.post("/postFormAct", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        console.log(req.files);
    });
});
```

Also there is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="/postFormAct" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="user"><br>
    <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="file" name="userPic"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Your code works for me once I add in the missing dependencies `mime` and `isLoggedIn`, though I assume they aren't missing for you. Have you tried logging `err` to confirm there wasn't an error? Have you tried putting logging in your `destination` and `filename` function to see whether they're being called? Could it be a file-system permissions issue? Have you tried using an absolute path instead of a relative path?

Comment: i tried logging, and there isnt any error. Maybe there is something wrong with the form because i try every solution and every time i get an empty array or undefined req.files

Comment: Your form pretty good but just add another `<input type="file" name="userPic"><br>` above the submit and check .There is nothing wrong  with code . I have executed your code and its working for me. just for testing purpose remove isLoggedIn and execute code.

Comment: ok the problem was other module blocking multer from work. Now its fixed. Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have an issue with your function level middleware, you have `isLoggedIn`, you have to chain the multer middleware `upload` right after like so :

```
// ...
var upload = multer({ storage : storage }).array('userPic');

app.post("/postFormAct", isLoggedIn, upload, function(req, res){
    console.log(req.files)
});
```

Here's a full working example :

```
const app = require('express')()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const multer = require('multer')
const morgan = require('morgan')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
})

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(morgan('dev'))

isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('check if user is logged in')
    next()
}

app.post('/uploads', isLoggedIn, upload.array('images'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    return res.send(req.files);
})

app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log(`server is listenning on port 8000`)
})
```

You can find a test repository [here](https://github.com/sapher/stacko-46987140)

Also make sure that your destination dir exist.

Comment: I've tried to copypaste that working example and even this code doesnt put images in my uploads folder, and when i try to console log req.files its still an empty array

Comment: ok the problem was other module blocking multer from work. Now its fixed. Thanks for help

Comment: @rafalos - which module was blocking multer from working? GridFS by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `var upload = multer({ storage : storage }).array('userPic');`
use

`var upload = multer({ storage : storage }).any('userPic');`

**.any()**

Accepts all files that comes over the wire. An array of files will be stored in `req.files`.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered something about Express middleware with multer.
You need to pass an array as middleware if you have more than one function that needs to act as middleware.

So this:

```js
app.post('/uploads', isLoggedIn, upload.array('images'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    return res.send(req.files);
})
```

should become this:

```js
app.post('/uploads', [upload.array('images'), isLoggedIn], (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    return res.send(req.files);
})
```

**Note:** Also notice that the upload middleware needs to go first...I don't know why this happens but that's the only way it worked for me.

I'm just putting this out there if anyone needs help with this(even though the question is pretty old and has an accepted answer).